# Bash - When to use '$' in front of variables?

Tags: bash

I'm very new to bash scripting, and as I've been searching for information online I've found a lot of seemingly contradictory advice. The thing I'm most confused about is the $ in front of variable names. My main question is, when is and isn't it appropriate to use that syntax? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically, it is used when referring to the variable, but not when defining it.

When you define a variable you do not use it:

```
value=233
```

You have to use them when you call the variable:

```
echo "$value"
```

There are some exceptions to this basic rule. For example in math expresions, as [etarion comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18658190/bash-when-to-use-in-front-of-variables/18658211#comment27475338_18658211).

---

> one more question: if I declare an array my_array and iterate through
>   it with a counter i, would the call to that have to be $my_array[$i]?

See the example:

```
$ myarray=("one" "two" "three")
$ echo ${myarray[1]}     #note that the first index is 0
two
```

To iterate through it, this code makes it:

```
for item in "${myarray[@]}"
do
  echo $item
done
```

In our case:

```
$ for item in "${myarray[@]}"; do echo $item; done
one
two
three
```

Comment: Thanks, one more question: if I declare an array my_array and iterate through it with a counter i, would the call to that have to be $my_array[$i]?

Comment: That is not entirely correct. For example, in math context you don't use it when refering to the variable - `x = 2; y = 1; let z=++x*++y; echo $z`

Comment: Change ``echo $value`` to ``echo "$value"``

Comment: @fedorqui Thanks, I'm still a little unsure how to do this within a loop though. It seems like getting a static location's fairly simple, but if I have an iterator i declared, how do I get the ith spot?

Comment: @thnkwthprtls I just updated again showing how to iterate through an array. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I am no bash user that knows too much. But whenever you declare variable you would not use the $, and whenever you want to call upon that variable and use its value you would use the $ sign.